# How to use a submit a one-to-many form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-views

I have a list of employees who work at a site. Each site is owned by a User (using Django's standard user model).

I want to create a form that adds an employee and automatically links them to a site dependent on who the authenticated user is:

models.py:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, null=True)
    employee_name = models.CharField(default='name', max_length=128, blank=False, null=False)

class Site(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    site_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False, null=False)
```

views.py:

```
site_profile = Site.objects.get(user=request.user)

if request.method == "POST":
    form = EmployeeAddForm( request.POST )
    if form.is_valid():

        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.site = site_profile
        obj.save()

        return redirect('dashboard_home')

form = EmployeeAddForm()

return render(request, "dashboard/employees.html",  {'form': form })
```

forms.py:

```
class EmployeeAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
      class Meta:
            model = Employee
            fields = ( 'employee_name')
```

This code will add the employee to the database, but in django admin, `list_display = 'site'` results in `Site object` not the actual site name. It does not appear that the employee is linked to the site.

If I use `obj.site = site_profile.id` (adding `.id`), I get the error `Cannot assign "1": "Employee.site" must be a "Site" instance.`

Comment: Not sure I understand. Each specific site is a object created from the Site class. What do you see that makes you think you're getting the wrong behavior?

Comment: @Alain in django admin, `list_display = 'site'` results in `Site object` not the actual site name. It does not appear that the employee is linked to the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error: the above code is correct, I simply had a tab ordering error in my Site modeL

```
class Site(models.Model):
...

def __str__(self):
    return self.site_name
```

`def` should have been inserted 1 tab inwards.